# Hard to make JSNI work with Errai

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm finding it hard to make JSNI work directly with Errai, take for example this code:

```
private static native void _createCallOut(JavaScriptObject callout)/*-{
    $wnd.hopscotch.getCalloutManager().createCallout(callout);
}-*/;
```

Where this JSNI is called roothing from

```
@PageShowing
public void onShow() {
                CallOut startCallOut = new CallOut("dashboard", Placement.RIGHT);
                startCallOut.setTitle("Take an example tour");
                startCallOut.setContent("Start by taking an example tour to see GWT-Tour in action!");
                startCallOut.setWidth(240);
                startCallOut.centerXOffset();
                startCallOut.centerArrowOffset();
                GwtTour.createCallOut(startCallOut); // Here!
}
```

Where this Java code, `CallOut` works fine if the first parameter is the ID of a DIV that is manually typed into the GWT app HTML, but if its on the page template of Errai, this will not work. Any ideas why its not working?

Comment: Are you sure the div has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@PageShowing` lifecycle method is invoked *before* the template has been added to the DOM. From the `PageShowing` JavaDoc:

> Indicates that the target method should be called when the `@Page`
>   widget it is a member of is about to be displayed in the
>   navigation content panel: after the widget's `@PageState` fields
>   have been updated and before it is displayed in the navigation content
>   panel.

Try using `@PageShown` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried @PageShown but it did not work either, in onAttach however it did worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work instead in `@PageShowing` or `@PageShown`, but inside `onAttach` or the `@Page`:

```
@Override
protected void onAttach() {
      super.onAttach();
      // Works fine inside
    }
```